# Microsoft.CustomDictionaryDeployment fails even if search content access account has reading permissions

Tags: permissions, 2013, crawl

I have a problem with my SharePoint 2013 installation, that is driving me nuts. The same error appears in the event logs every 10 minutes:

> The Execute method of job definition 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CustomDictionaryDeploymentJobDefinition'(ID 9bc98c89-33c9-41e4-ae77-291374f254974045149c-1b98-3007-084b-a2c9b948a7b0) threw an exception. More information is included below.  Failed to run flow Microsoft.CustomDictionaryDeployment. Correlation Id: 6c6dfa9b-60fb-106c-1067-9f0ff5915935.

It is a fresh install of SP2013 on Server 2012 with AD and SQL on external servers. I did not define any custom dictionaries and I made sure, that my search content access account (SP_Crawl) has reading permissions to the managed metadata service application (as suggested [here](http://get-sharepoint.com/2013/04/failed-to-run-flow-microsoft-customdictionarydeployment/)). Still the error keeps coming.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Please give your search content account access to the managed metadata service application:
http://get-sharepoint.com/2013/04/failed-to-run-flow-microsoft-customdictionarydeployment/

** EDIT: Above I stated content access account, it should be the service account (windows) that's running search.  Apologies for confusion.

Comment: -1 That's the same page the OP links to in the question, saying it didn't work.

Comment: Hello - he must not have added the permissions correctly, I can assure you this corrects the issue

Comment: Unfortunately that's a discussion you'll have to have with them. If you have any hints as to how to better implement the recommendations in the link then that may help. But as it stands you're recommending steps that they've specifically said didn't work for them.

Comment: The OP says he used the content access account, not the search service account, which is what @Ryan suggested in his edit and what the linked page recommends.  Although I suppose if both things are the same account there must be some other issue.

Comment: +1 Search Service account is the one you should add. Just had the issue and was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Add read access for your Default Content Access Account (that you find in the Search Service Application) in the Managed Metadata Service Application.

1. Central Admin
2. Application Management
3. Manage Service Applications
4. Select the Managed Metadata Service
5. Clock *Permissions* in the ribbon
6. Give your Default Content Access Account Read Access to Term Store

[image]

Comment: And what If there is no `Managed Metadata Service` defined?

Comment: @Emaborsa I quess you shouldn't get that particular error...

Comment: @Emaborsa If there is no Managed Metadata Service, you should create one. Go to New->Managed Metadata Service. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/configure-the-managed-metadata-service